# Access members of unkown template type of derived template class through pointer to base class C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I need to have a map holding different value types. I achieved that using a derived template class `Derived` of type `T` derived from `B`  and declaring my map using a pointer to the base class `Base` like so:

```
class Base {
    public:
    ~Base(){}
};

template <class T>
class Derived: public Base {
     public:
     Derived(T value) {
          this->value = value;
     }
     T value;
 };

 std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> my_map;

 using KeyValuePair = std::pair<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>;

 my_map.insert(KeyValuePair("foo1",std::make_shared<Derived<int>>(10)));
 my_map.insert(KeyValuePair("foo2",std::make_shared<Derived<double>>(20.0)));
 my_map.insert(KeyValuePair("foo3",std::make_shared<Derived<std::string>>("bla")));
```

I now for example want to print the value of a map entry

```
 for (auto const& x : my_map)
{
    std::cout << *x.get() << std::endl;
}
```

However, I now have the problem that I cannot access the the members in the `Derived` class by casting `x` to `Derived`, because I don't know the type of the template parameter. So the following is not possible:

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived<?>> derived = std::dynamic_cast<Derived<?>>(x);
```

I thought about having a virtual function in the `Base` class which returns the member, but I don't know the return type, so not an option.

I also don't want to specify several virtual functions for several return types, as the whole point of the code is to avoid copying code and having a "generic map"

However, I don't see another solution besides using some fancy boost magic by returning a streamable boost::any like the following, as this removes any information about the type.

```
 using streamable_any = boost::type_erasure::any<boost::mpl::vector<
 boost::type_erasure::copy_constructible<>,
 boost::type_erasure::destructible<>,
 boost::type_erasure::ostreamable<>>>;
```

What are the possibilities I have to achieve what I want? I suspect that I need to consider a design change.

Comment: Is there a reason you want inheritance at all?

Comment: You should look into `boost::variant` or `std::variant` if you can use C++17

Comment: How many operations do you want to perform on the type `T` approximetally?

Comment: How many types `T` do you have?  Is the list bounded and enumerable somewhere, or not?

Comment: @Yakk: I will have only a few basic types `T`, not more than 10. I only need to be able to set and get the value of `T`

Comment: @sfun Getting and setting the value of `T` is a different operation for each type.  Printing any `T` to an ostream is one operation, as the output (some string on some stream) is the same regardless of `T`'s type.  "*Just* getting and setting for each type `T` and possibly failing if the type doesn't match" is 10 different operations all of whom can fail at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for *printing*, you can add a single virtual method easily enough:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}

  virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Base const &b) {
    return b.print(os);
  }
};

template <class T>
class Derived: public Base {
  T value;
public:
  Derived(T v) : value(v) {}

  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const override {
      return os << value;
  }
};
```

However, if you need more general access to the value, your options are essentially:

1. Extract value as Boost.any (by virtual function)
2. Enumerate all legal types for `T`, and return a `Boost.variant<Ts>` (again by virtual function)
3. Enumerate all legal types and write a Visitor with overloads for each. Then implement a simple virtual visit method in `Base` and `Derived`. Note that `Derived<T>::apply(Visitor &v) { v.visit(value); }` will fail to compile if `T` doesn't match any overload of `visit`, and also that you need to take care when the valid types of T have implicit conversions.
4. You can avoid coupling your code to a pre-defined list of legal `T`s by writing a post-hoc visitor. This means manual dispatch, looking up the function to call using `std::type_index` as your key, and manual casting. It's ugly though.

Or (worst but most flexible) keep the streaming output and just re-parse the value from a stringstream. If you *must* do this, consider serializing to a well-defined format instead of (or as well as) just writing a pretty human-readable format.

Comment: Destructor must be virtual as well

Comment: @Slava Not if it is created only in a `shared_ptr` to `Derived<T>`, as `shared_ptr` type-erases the cleanup code.  But it is still probably a good idea.  ;)  (In fact, to force the shared ptr bit, you probably want a protected non-virtual destructor in the Base)

Comment: @Useless with usage of `boost::variant` there should be no inheritance at all, not that virtual function returns instance of `boost::variant`

Comment: The alternatives are: just use `boost::variant` instead of all this (in which case you're right), or add `boost:variant` after the fact. I probably should address both independently, but hadn't intended to expand on alternatives to the top-level design.

Comment: @Useless: I like the visitor approach, as I need to get used to using patterns. I will try both ways, visitor and boost::variant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have UB in your example, as you hold instances of derived classes through pointer of base, destructor must be virtual.

To fix your current problem with printing values you can add a virtual method:

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void print( std::ostream &os ) const = 0;
    virtual ~Base(){}
};
```

but that would only fix this particular problem, but accessing values would be still issue. One of solution would be to add a virtual getter that converts all values to `std::string`. Or always use cascade of `dynamic_cast<>` (note dynamic cast would require at least one virtual method in `Base`). But better to use `boost::variant` which provides functionality to implement visitor pattern and check if this instance holds value of particular type. You would not need inheritance at all in this case.

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding `friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, Base const& )`.

Comment: @Yakk yes it could, but I do not think this is viable solution in general

Answer (score 0):

Getting:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct types {};

template<class types, template<class...>class>
struct apply_to {};
template<class types, template<class...>class Z>
using apply_to_t=typename apply_to<types, Z>::type;
template<class...Ts, template<class...>class Z>
struct apply_to<types<Ts...>, Z>{ using type=Z<Ts...>; };

template<class types>
using variant_of=apply_to_t<types, boost::variant>;

using supported_types = types<int, double, std::string>;

class Base {
  virtual variant_of_t<supported_types> get() const = 0;
protected:
  ~Base() {}
};

template<class T>
class Derived final: public Base {
  T t;
public:
  virtual variant_of_t<supported_types> get() const override {
    return t;
  }
  virtual ~Derived() {}
};
```

Setting can be a bit trickier.

```
template<class...Ts>
using sink = boost::variant< std::function<void(Ts)>... >;

template<class types>
using setters = apply_to_t<types, sink>;

class Base {
  virtual variant_of_t<supported_types> get() const = 0;
  virtual void set( std::function<void(setters<supported_types>)> ) = 0;
protected:
  ~Base() {}
};

template<class T>
class Derived final: public Base {
  T t;
public:
  virtual void set( std::function<void(setters<supported_types>)> s ) override {
    s( std::function<void(T)>( [&](T&& in) { t = std::forward<T>(in); } ) );
  }
  virtual variant_of_t<supported_types> get() const override {
    return t;
  }
  virtual ~Derived() {}
};
```

which is a bit more insane.

This gives you type-safe get and set.  When you call `set`, you must pass in a lambda that can accept any type setter, and do the right thing.  When you call `get`, it returns a variant over the possibilities of the contained data, which you have to deal with.

Printing would look like:

```
for (auto const& x : my_map)
{
   if (!x) continue;
   boost::apply_visitor([&](auto&& x){ 
     std::cout << x << std::endl;
   }, x->get());
}
```

Suppose you want to set a value.

```
template<class...Fs>
struct override_t;
template<class F0, class F1, class...Fs>
struct override_t<F0, F1, Fs...>: F0, override_t<F1, Fs...> {
  using RBase=override_t<F1, Fs...>;
  using F0::operator();
  using RBase::operator();
  override_t( F0 f0, F1 f1, Fs... fs ):
    F0(std::move(f0)),
    RBase(std::move(f1), std::move(fs)...)
  {}
};
template<class F0>
struct override_t<F0>: F0 {
  using F0::operator();
  override_t( F0 f0 ):
    F0(std::move(f0))
  {}
};
template<>
struct override_t<> {};
template<class...Fs>
override_t<Fs...> override( Fs... fs ) { return {std::move(fs)...}; }

x->set(
  [&]( auto setters ) {
    boost::apply_visitor(
      override(
        [&]( std::function<void(int)> set ) {
          set(7);
        },
        [&]( auto&& ) {
           assert(false); // wrong type
        }
      ),
      setters
    );
  }
);
```

as type-safe setting of a value with unknown type is rather difficult to get right.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to make the class B a template, so it could have a method that returns a value of type T:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
    public:
    virtual T GetValue();
};
```

Another option is to have a virtual print method:

```
class Base {
    public:
    virtual void PrintValue();
};
```

Comment: How your first solution would work in the loop mentioned?

Comment: You would just call GetValue() in the loop and it will return a value of type T

Comment: No it would not. Try to implement that.

Comment: Provide example on ideone please

Comment: What you seem to mean is that you can't have derived objects with different template parameters in the same map. It works if they all have the same type

Comment: No I want example of `virtual T GetValue()` working in this case

Comment: But this doesn't enable me to do what I intended. If you change line 42 (or 43 or 44) to `Derived<double>`, it won't compile, which is not surprising

Comment: How that code sample is related to the OP question?